# Extract the value of each pixel within polygon

Tags: qgis

I have a vector layer defining a region. I have then loaded a DEM and made an aspect layer. How can i export the value of each pixel within the vector layer? I need to manipulate them in Excel

Answer (score 3):

[Clip by mask](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#gdalcliprasterbymasklayer) then [export to XYZ](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#gdalgdal2xyz) csv.